# Merging every nth column of all files in a directory

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, do.call

There are 22 text files which are seperated by tab inside a directory. Actually, i only need the 6th column of every text files and then merge them into one file. When i write these commands at the below;

```
filenames = list.files()
my.list = lapply(X = filenames, FUN = function(x) {read.table(x, sep = "\t")[,6]})
my.df <- do.call("cbind", my.list)
```

As a result of these commands; i have a my.df file with 22 columns but the values inside that columns are strangely not from the txt files. I could not find the source of these data.

Comment: Try `read.table(x, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,6]` or use `[, 6, drop = FALSE]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading the files the 6th column is converted into factor. We can keep character columns as character:

```
my.list = lapply(X = filenames, FUN = function(x) {
  read.table(x, sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,6]})
my.df <- do.call("cbind", my.list)
```

Or we can keep data.frame as data.frame when subsetting 6th column:

```
my.list = lapply(X = filenames, FUN = function(x) {
  read.table(x, sep = "\t")[, 6, drop = FALSE]})
my.df <- do.call("cbind", my.list)
```